# any working way for vertical scrolling of text automatically in view android java

Tags: java, android

I know that this topic is asked many times on this website but all the responses so far haven't been very helpful to me.

what i am trying is to vertical scroll the text automatically from example i have to scroll the text from strings and the text should be directly on the relative layout from `topmargin = 2 to bottommargin = 20` and then keeps looping once the all text is shown from the strings

any working way ?

you can see this video what i am looking for

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dL3lp5_N4VA

i didn't found where to start properly because none works now i am thinking if anybody have working code for this

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did exactly this for a Christmas present for my daughter. My solution was to put the text in a `ScrollView` and programmatically scroll with a `Runnable` that reschedules itself if there is still more content to scroll.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/background"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/leading_space"
                tools:layout_height="1dp"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_a_long_time_ago"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/trailing_space"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/a_long_time_ago"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
                    style="@style/Text"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/episode_2015"
                    style="@style/Text.Episode"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/merry_christmas"
                    style="@style/Text.Title"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_crawl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="@string/opening_text"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
                style="@style/Text"
                />

            <!--
            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/trailing_space"
                tools:layout_height="1dp"
                />
                -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_next"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/leading_space"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview_lightsabers"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/lightsaber"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/lightsabers"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="@string/click_to_continue"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    style="@style/Text.Title"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code snippet from my `Activity`:

```
private ScrollView _scrollView;

private Runnable _smoothScrollRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        _scrollView.smoothScrollBy(2, 2);

        if (_scrollView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
            _scrollView.postDelayed(_smoothScrollRunnable, 75);
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    _scrollView.post(_smoothScrollRunnable);
}
```

Result (video quality sucks and it wasn't finished yet but you get the idea):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfKxGraLNLA

**Edit:**

Response to the comment:

> hi sir i liked you way it works when the text is more than the screen ,can is this be implemented something like to scroll the text till some height and then back like up and down in loop till some width ?

Sure it could be modified to do that. Check out the [`ScrollView.canScrollVertically`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#canScrollVertically%28int%29) method:

> `public boolean canScrollVertically (int direction)`
>
> Check if this view can be scrolled vertically in a certain direction.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `direction` - Negative to check scrolling up, positive to check scrolling down.
>
> **Returns**
>
> `boolean` - true if this view can be scrolled in the specified direction, false otherwise.

And the [`ScrollView.smoothScrollBy`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollBy%28int,%20int%29) method:

> `public final void smoothScrollBy (int dx, int dy)`
>
> Like `scrollBy(int, int)`, but scroll smoothly instead of immediately.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `dx` - the number of pixels to scroll by on the X axis
>
> `dy` - the number of pixels to scroll by on the Y axis

So if you modified the code snippet to remember which direction you were scrolling (up or down) and then flip it when you couldn't go any further you would achieve what you are looking for.

**Edit:**

Quick, incomplete, code snippet to explain what I'm talking about:

```
private boolean isScrollingDown = true;
private Runnable _smoothScrollRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (isScrollingDown && !_scrollView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
            // We can't scroll down any further so start scrolling up ...
            isScrollingDown = false;
        } else if (!isScrollingDown && !_scrollView.canScrollVertically(-1) {
            // We can't scroll up any further so start scrolling down ...
            isScrollingDown = true;
        }

        if (isScrollingDown) {
            // Scroll down by 2
            _scrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, 2);
        } else {
            // Scroll up by 2
            _scrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, -2);          
        }

        // Just keep scrolling forever ...
        _scrollView.postDelayed(_smoothScrollRunnable, 75);
    }
};
```

Comment: hi sir i liked you way it works when the text is more than the screen ,can is this be implemented something like to scroll the text till some height and then back like up and down in loop till top and then in loop till that initialized height ?

Comment: @android_guy yes. Updated my answer with supporting documentation.

Comment: hello sir i can understand this but maybe i am doing wrong something   if (_scrollView.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
             _scrollView.postDelayed(_smoothScrollRunnable, 75);
         }    seems it is not scrolling up when done at down can you edit bit to help me thanks you sir  PS i guess smoothscroll also does reflect the changes

Comment: @android_guy I added a quick code snippet to show scrolling down until you can't scroll down anymore and then scrolling up until you can't go up anymore. It should get you started.

Comment: perfectly sir ,this one will be the best answer on stackoverflow ever for scrolling text   just i am having trouble with this  http://oi68.tinypic.com/2rhqzhf.jpg    now believe the text is only this much not more than screen i changed the what you have described in smoothscroll but it has no effect other than that everything is working fine,if we can scroll this text above the layout i mean actionbar and when text end bring the text down till the height for example 500px